# Create a masked overlay with draggable/resizable underneath

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to get kineticjs down and worked out a little app which makes my images draggable and resizable. So far so good;

However: I want an overlay with a variable height/width block in the center which should show the image underneath(With the draggable/resizable intact) with a semi-transparent overlay.

I want to be able to still resize/drag behind the overlay while the overlay is still intact(Like this, but with kineticjs: http://envyum.nl/pointer/)

Is there a way to do so? By cutting a block out of an overlaying rectangle perhaps? And can the mouse ignore the overlay such as `pointer-events: none` can in css3?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you post some of the code of what you have in a working jsfiddle? that way others (like me) can help you out more by adding some code

Comment: it also seems that the simplest way to achieve an 'overlay' is to create a new layer with four semi-transparent rectangles that dont listen for any events so that you can drag the image behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a sample of what I was talking about in the comments above: http://jsfiddle.net/KwQBB/

This did not require a new layer, but might be good practice to do so.

You can tailor the logic to be whatever you want, especially to simulate a 'cut-out'

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 500
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var pentagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    sides: 5,
    radius: 70,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true,
    dragOnTop: false
  });
  var rect1 = new Kinetic.Rect({  // overlay
    x: 0,
    y: 0, 
    width: stage.getWidth(),
    height: 100,
    fill: 'gray',
    opacity: 0.5,
    listening: false     // <------ Extremely important
  });
  var rect2 = new Kinetic.Rect({ // overlay
    x: 0,
    y: stage.getHeight()/2, 
    width: stage.getWidth(),
    height: 100,
    fill: 'gray',
    opacity: 0.5,
    listening: false     // <------ Extremely important
  });

  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(pentagon);
  layer.add(rect1);
  layer.add(rect2);   // add more rectangles to complete overlay

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
```

Comment: I've tried the rectangle thing. But since it's a 100% width and height thing it comes short sometimes leaving me with ugly white lines in between impossible to correct properly. Nevertheless; seeing your example makes me want to try again! Thanks for helping me out thus far!

Comment: And done trying: http://www.envyum.nl/pointer/
As you can see that if you drag, the image gets on top of the overlay. Could you check my JS to see if you can find some abnormalities? (Since it's my first time using canvas and kinetic) http://www.envyum.nl/pointer/javascript/fertile_imager3.js

Comment: Ok, i'm clearly an idiot. I forgot the "DragOnTop" on my image. Thanks for helping me out!